lenovo M90a, Ubuntu 24.04, missing sound on speakers, earphones ok
lenovo M90a Ubuntu 24.04 missing sound on speakers, earphones ok
$ lspci | grep -i audio ->
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller (rev 11). 6.8.0-47-generic
$ lsb_release -a ->
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
I own two Leovo AllInOne machines and two Ubuntu USB Live Sticks (Ubuntu 24.04 and 20.04)
On the old machine, both live systems are working without any problems without any settings.
On the new M90A, neither work. I don't have a working Windows live system because I don't have a license. An x.iso downloaded from Micro$oft won't start.
Ubuntu 24.04 is installed on the new machine and I've been trying for hours and hours. I can't get any sound out of the speakers.
